# Block Google Play installing certain applications

Tags: google-play-store

I want to block the Google Play Store from installing a certain list of applications or only allow the Google Play Store to install that list of applications.

Is there any way to write a program to do that?

Comment: Are you trying to get rid of stock applications that your phone won't allow you to remove?

Comment: All the applications are fine.  I am preventing the users trying to install some apps that the admin doesn't allow them to install on the mobile phone.  To make an example, suppose a corporation distributes company-controlled phones to its employees but the company doesn't want its employees to install any app that the company doesn't allow.

Comment: So you're probably looking into some kind of "device administrator" stuff. I'm not familiar with that, but the keyword might prove helpful to your search ;)

Comment: If you really want to know about writing an app to do this, then this question is better suited for Stack Overflow. A moderator can migrate it for you if you flag the question and ask them nicely. I've not flagged your post myself in case there's some non-development solution to your problem. In the meantime, it's possible to use a Broadcast Receiver to receive "package installed" events, and may be possible to use the [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) to uninstall them.

Answer (score 1):

Your specific question is:

> Is there any way to write a program to do that?

Yes, it would be hard for the Android programmer novice, but it can be done. It would be a lot easier to do with root permission as well. For a long time companies liked to stick with BlackBerry because they were easier to 'child lock'. More and more, I am actually seeing people with IPhones now having this 'company child lock software'.

I'm sure companies out there are making software for Android devices that inhibit the use of certain apps and prevent downloading them all together. You could probably pay to get this software onto a device but it would probably be very expensive.

Comment: There's also the BYOD (Bring Your Own Device) model they could use. That's like Samsung Knox (expect to see more of this sort of thing in Android going forward, but that's not official yet shhh). You have your apps and your things yourself, but the secure Knox part of the device will only allow enterprise / white listed applications to be installed. Any custom kernels / ROMs will trigger Knox permanently and might be a good corporate solution. For the record: I HATE Knox, but that's another conversation!